# Why a TypeScript project generated with Create React App can find modules and an Express one doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express, webstorm

I use WebStorm, I created a React project and an Express project with a build-in wizard. I manually added TypeScript to the latter.
Here's my `tsconfig.json` for React:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

And here's one for express:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "output",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJS" : true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "source/**/*"
  ]
}
```

For the express project I needed to set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

**The problem:** when I use `import` in the React project I don't need to add the extension `.js` to file names, but in the Express project it's necessary, otherwise I'm getting `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND`.

```
import {serviceRouter} from "./ServiceRouter";
```

vs

```
import {serviceRouter} from "./ServiceRouter.js";
```

Comment: one of the issues is that your include should be: `"include": ["source/**/*.ts"]`

Comment: @TomBombadil The react project's configuration simply names the directory and it still works the way it should.

Answer (score 1):

When using ES6 modules (`"type": "module"`), extensions are mandatory, see https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions